# How to prove that $f(x,y) = xe^{−2x^2−y^2}$ has a global maximum and a global minimum

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta, maxima-minima

We know that a function defined on a closed bounded domain must have a maximum and a minimum, But $f(x,y) = xe^{−2x^2−y^2}$ is defined on the domain $R^2$, which is not closed bounded, so how to show that it actually has a global max and a global min?

I am trying to prove that outside a disk with distance d, the absolute value of the function value can be as small as possible. That is, for all $\epsilon>0$, exist $d>0$ such that $||(x,y)-(0,0)||>d$ implies $||f(x,y)||<\epsilon$ But how may I  prove that? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes. This is indeed the correct way to approach this problem

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. Notice that $|x|\leq\Vert (x,y)\Vert$, and $e^{-2x^2-y^2}\leq e^{-\Vert (x,y)\Vert^2}$.

Comment: @zuggg Yes, but could you please extend your answer? I cannot find a proper way to control $xe^{-2x^2-y^2}$ so far.

Comment: Use the inequalities I mentioned, and the fact that the function $r\mapsto re^{-r^2}$ tends to $0$ as $r\to\infty$ to find exactly what you wanted to. You do not need an explicit control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $(x,y) \in R^2$ such that $r:=||(x,y)|| > 0$. Then we have $2x^2+y^2 \ge x^2+y^2=r^2$, thus $e^{-2x^2-y^2} \le e^{-r^2}$. This gives

$$|f(x,y)| \le \frac{r}{e^{r^2}}$$